# Write-through with SQL tables in Apache Ignite

Tags: ignite

Is it possible to configure write-through into an external database for caches created using SQL statements in Apache Ignite?

From what I have seen in the documentation there isn't any way to specify write-through configuration when creating a table using `CREATE TABLE` and once a cache is created, it's not possible to alter its configuration from Java.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [cache template](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/configuring-caches/configuration-overview#cache-templates). But the best answer is that you don't need to create a table using the CREATE TABLE command. If you create your table in XML/Java, you can still access it using SQL but you also have more control over its structure (including the cache store).

Comment: I didn't think of that! let me try it out.

Comment: I created a cache template for the table, but unfortunately when I call create table with the template, I get 'Template cache already contains query entities which it should not'. The whole SQL DDL topic is strangely designed. I used SQL DDLs from an existing database which would help with the migration of the existing application a lot, the ability to use jdbc and SQL querying fortunately works well.

Comment: Query entities are just how you define SQL, so they should not be in your template definition.